# Unexpected keyword argument when running Lightgbm on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, lightgbm

When running the code below:

```
import lightgbm as lgb

params = {'num_leaves': 38,              
          'min_data_in_leaf': 50,
          'objective': 'regression',     
          'max_depth': -1,                
          'learning_rate': 0.1,           
          'device': 'gpu'
          }
trn_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)
val_data = lgb.Dataset(x_test, y_test)

model = lgb.train(params,
                trn_data,
                20000,
                valid_sets=[trn_data, val_data],
                verbose_eval=300,
                early_stopping_rounds=1000)
```

I get the follow errors:

```
train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose_eval'
train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'early_stopping_rounds'
```

It is important to note that I run this on GPU. When running it on CPU i do not get this error.

Has anyone got an idea how I can incorporate a verbose output and early stopping rounds when running Lightgbm on GPU??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Lightgbm on GPU you can check the official documentation. On documentation there are no configuration option as vebose_ecal and early_stopping_rounds
[Official Documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/GPU-Tutorial.html)

Also you can check this link [Running LightGBM on GPU with python](https://www.kaggle.com/code/abhishek/running-lightgbm-on-gpu/notebook)

Comment: do you have an idea how i can display the output whilst running lightgbm on gpu using python?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an idea. You can ask a new question with your intention and example scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

In new lightGBM version, verbose_eval is integrated in callbacks func winthin train class, called log_evaluation
u can find it in [official documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.log_evaluation.html), so do the early_stopping

According to new docs, u can user verbose_eval like this

```
import lightgbm as lgb

params = {'num_leaves': 38,              
          'min_data_in_leaf': 50,
          'objective': 'regression',     
          'max_depth': -1,                
          'learning_rate': 0.1,           
          'device': 'gpu'
          }
trn_data = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)
val_data = lgb.Dataset(x_test, y_test)

model = lgb.train(params,
                trn_data,
                20000,
                valid_sets=[trn_data, val_data],
                **callbacks=[lgb.early_stopping(stopping_rounds=50), lgb.log_evaluation(50)]**)
```

Comment: I would recommend expanding more on this answer

Comment: This solution didn't work for me in Python3.11, LightGBM4.2.0. The working solution for me is to first uninstall the newer version of LightGBM, then install older version with command such as: pip install lightgbm==3.3.0

Comment: @GoodWill Looked into [Changelog](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/releases). Guys are deprecating arguments in minor releases left and right. Apparently, Micro$oft prefers [sentimental versioning](https://github.com/dominictarr/sentimental-versioning/tree/master) approach.